# aws - autoscaling group - attach detach ebs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-auto-scaling

I have a special requirement , where i can have only 1 ec2 in my asg at a time. There is supposed to be some persistent data , for which i want to use ebs. Ideal case is, one ec2 comes up and while starting up , it attaches the ebs and while terminating it detaches the ebs. The replacement ebs should wait for ebs to be detached from previous ec2 and attach to itself when available, then become inService.

I have been searching around on solutions for this. There doesnt seem to be anything straigh forward, in fact it looks like this may not be a common usecase. I am relatively new to aws.

Simplest i could think was create lifecycle hooks - for autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING.

Subscribe to ASG lifecycle events to SNS, trigger lambda based on this TERMINATING event. lambda could run ssm on the instance ( unmount volume and then detach ebs , send sns notification about completion and set lifecycle hook as complete).
Similarly on starting instance autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING, do the same to attach ebs and complete hook.
-is this a feasible solution for this requirement or wouldnt be a good way to go about this problem?

Comment: ok...so why do you need asg if you will have only 1 EC2 instance at a time?

Comment: @Riz asg can re-create ec2 based on healthchecks , also in case of node failure rebuild the ec2.

Comment: For a "shared" EBS volume like this, IMO the best thing to do is discover and mount it via user data script at startup (eg use awscli to attach the ebs to the running instance and standard `mount` command once attached). You can't make the volume part of the scaling group config.

Comment: ok..it depends on your data. You can think of EFS if it suits your application.

Comment: @Riz, EFS doesnt suit my application as i dont want it attached to 2 instances at a time, which can happen when 1 instance is unhealthy and another comes up.

Comment: @jordanm GCP has an option of stateful instance gorups which is exactly what i need.

Comment: When an instance is unhealthy, no requests will be routed to it, it won't do anything usefull anyway, so what's the issue if NFS is attached to it for few seconds(the time taken between new healthy node and termination of unhealthy one)? BTW there are ways to make it not attached to both at the same time(hint: make use of eventbridge which triggers a lambda which mounts EFS once the old EC2 is terminated.) I repeat, it's not a very good use of autoscaling. What guarantee do you have that a replacement asg node will be healthy? YOu will get stuck in a loop of unhealthy replacing instances.

Comment: You need an automation to create a new node from an ami when your node gets unhealthy.

Comment: @Riz most likely will use efs. i realise its not good use of asg but i am stuck with an application that was written a million years ago and is not 'cloud friendly' .

Comment: As for the EBS, is it root volume or secondary? If root, you can make your ami and create `launch template` with your ami instead of getting one from marketplace. If it's secondary, you can either follow what jordanm said or you can make use of lambda and eventbridge and attach and mount once the isntance is up but still in pending: wait state.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach of using lifecycle hooks with AWS Auto Scaling and Lambda functions to handle the attachment and detachment of EBS volumes in your specific use case is indeed a feasible solution. It allows you to have control over the lifecycle of EC2 instances and the associated EBS volumes.

Here's a high-level overview of the steps involved in implementing this solution:

Configure Auto Scaling Group (ASG):

Set the desired capacity of the ASG to 1 so that only one EC2 instance is running at a time.
Enable lifecycle hooks for the ASG's termination event.
Set up SNS Topic and Subscription:

Create an SNS topic to receive notifications from the ASG.
Subscribe a Lambda function to the SNS topic to receive these notifications.
Create Lambda Functions:

Write a Lambda function that handles the termination event.
When triggered by the SNS notification, the function should execute the necessary steps to unmount and detach the EBS volume from the terminating instance.
Once the detachment is complete, it should notify the ASG to complete the lifecycle hook.
Write another Lambda function that handles the launch event.
When triggered by the SNS notification, the function should attach the EBS volume to the launching instance.
After the attachment is successful, it should notify the ASG to complete the lifecycle hook.
Associate Lambda Functions with SNS Events:

Configure the SNS topic to invoke the appropriate Lambda function for each event (termination and launch).
By following this approach, the lifecycle hooks will ensure that the EBS volume is detached from the terminating instance before it is attached to the launching instance. This allows you to maintain the persistence of the data stored on the EBS volume across instance replacements.

Remember to test and validate the solution thoroughly before deploying it to production. Also, consider implementing error handling and retries in your Lambda functions to handle any potential failures during the attachment or detachment process.

While this solution may require some custom development and configuration, it provides the desired control and ensures the EBS volume is properly attached and detached during instance lifecycle transitions.